# How to bit shift a bytes in solidity / assembly?

Tags: solidity, assembly, bit-manipulation

I can bit shift `uint_n_` easily but I don't manage to bit shift a `bytes memory myBytes`.

When doing `myBytes << i` I have a compile error and when using assembly I receive 0.

See my MWE for assembly and test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library BytesShift {
    function shiftLeft(bytes memory x, uint256 n)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        bytes memory tmp;
        assembly {
            tmp := shl(n, x)
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

```
describe("BytesShift", function () {
  describe("shiftLeft", () => {
    it(`Should shift bytes to the left`, async function () {
      const BytesShift = await ethers.getContract("BytesShift");
      const res = await BytesShift.shiftLeft("0xff", 1);
      expect(res).to.equal("0xfe");
    });
  });
});
```

failing with received value :

```
      AssertionError: expected '0x' to equal '0xfe'
      + expected - actual

      -0x
      +0xfe
```

Comment: How long is byte array? If it is less or equal to 32 you could use bytes32 instead of bytes and the shift should work.

Comment: I am considering this actually, split my `bytes` into chunks of `bytes32`

Comment: Why do you have to shift a bytes array? What are the possible values for the shift length? It has a bad smell shifting a bytes array of arbitrary length.

Comment: it's a custom encoding of data for on-chain NFTs, I didn't mean to advertise here but you can find out more on our page https://chaindreamers.xyz/on-chain-storage

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea shifting byte arrays. If necessary I'd do it off-chain or use some kind of DSL.

Comment: what is DSL? And why do you think it is a bad idea? I am interested in learning more! thx

Comment: DSL in this context is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language, e.g. you do not perform the shift but returns something like `Shift(byteArray,8)` so in the frontend the shift will be performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shift operation is only available for value types not for reference types (see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#value-types)

Value types exist on stack and there can be passed to the shift opcode.

The `bytes memory` only stores the location of the data in memory on stack. So in you assembly example  you `tmp` just points to an invalid memory location and therefore returns 0.

If you want to shift a bytes you need to process the whole bytes data word by word and also handle overflows between the words.

Comment: I do have a working solution with a `for` loops but I am looking for some gas saving and I thought that `assembly` could be a good start. thanks for the link